# Evaluate a logical expression string in python without using eval

Tags: python, logical-operators

Is there a quick way (library function) to evaluate an expression like the one below in python without using eval? (Evaluating strings using eval looks dangerous)

```
var1 = True
var2 = False
expression = "var1 | var2"
```

Comment: Have you looked into using [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval)?

Comment: Evaluating a string is always tricky and (almost) never a good idea. Maybe you could share why you need that. Maybe there's a better way.

Comment: I want to have user defined rules where they specify logical expressions that needs to be validated. Like "Age >24 && Weight < 100"